# Eclipse Custom Page wizard adding boilerplate

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have developed a wizard to generate my page and it successfully generates my page.  I have been digging for hours trying to find information on adding boilerplate code to the page.

Is there some information someone may have?

This is the final step on the page wizard:

```
private void doFinish(String containerName, String fileName,
        IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    // create a sample file
    monitor.beginTask("Creating " + fileName, 2);
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IResource resource = root.findMember(new Path(containerName));
    if (!resource.exists() || !(resource instanceof IContainer)) {
        throwCoreException("Container \"" + containerName
                + "\" does not exist.");
    }
    IContainer container = (IContainer) resource;
    final IFile file = container.getFile(new Path(fileName));
    try {
        InputStream stream = openContentStream();
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.setContents(stream, true, true, monitor);
        } else {
            file.create(stream, true, monitor);
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Comment: "generate my page" ... please elaborate, what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method openContentStream() is where you provide that boilerplate.  Simply override the method and have your implementation return the boilerplate you want via the returned InputStream.

If you want more control over the boilerplate generation, take a look at the Eclipse M2T-JET project.  JET was built to make tasks like this very simple.

Comment: I meant to take this down 5 minutes ago but yes that is where I added my code.  I have not looked at this wizard in over a month.